# CONCAT() using a date variable, which is converted into a character using to_char, and two other string variables

Tags: sql, concatenation, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is my first time using SQL Developer.
I want to create a string variable that contains the combined value of string `todate2`, `portfolio` and `node_name`. However, when I try to include `todate2` in the concat function, I obtain an error.
DATA_TYPE: `to_date` is a DATE, `portfolio` is a VARCHAR2(15 CHAR), `node_name` is a VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)

The code that returns an error:

```
select to_char(to_date, 'ddmmyyyy') todate2, to_char(to_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') todate, 
concat(concat(**todate2**,portfolio),node_name) as comb,
 portfolio, node_name,
 node_no, 
 sort
FROM table1
WHERE 1=1


ORDER BY 
  to_date asc,
  node_no asc
  ;
```

Alternatively, I have tried:

```
select  to_char(to_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') todate, 
concat(concat(**to_char(to_date, 'ddmmyyyy')**,portfolio),node_name) as comb,
 portfolio, node_name,
 node_no, 
 sort
FROM table1
WHERE 1=1


ORDER BY 
  to_date asc,
  node_no asc
  ;
```

This is my first time asking a question concerning SQL. Please do not hesitate to ask for more information if the information I have provided is insufficient.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What errors do you get? The first one will complain because you can't use a column alias in the same level of query, except in order-by, so todate2 is an invalid identifier. The second one looks OK - though using function names as column names is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `CONCAT`, it - in Oracle - accepts only two parameters. Use the double pipe `||` concatenation operator instead:

```
select to_char(todate2, 'ddmmyyyy') || ' '|| portfolio ||' '|| node_name
from table1
where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first query you define `todate2` as an alias for a column expression. You can't use an alias in the same level of query, except in the order by clause; this is due to the order the SQL is processed and evaluated. So that query will get error "ORA-00904: "TODATE2": invalid identifier".

If you had a complicated calculation or expression then you could use a subquery (i.e. an inline view or a common table expression, also know as subquery factoring) to define the alias, and that would then be available to an outer query. That seems like overkill here.

Your second query works as it is, but you could switch to the concatenation operator as @Littlefoot suggested:

```
select  to_char(to_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') todate, 
  to_char(to_date, 'ddmmyyyy') || portfolio || node_name as comb,
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=743fff86774136d2473d3b762e8591d4)